# LINQ Join / Union two lists of objects taking precedence from second over first

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have two lists of ActionItem objects:

```
ListA<ActionItem>;
ListB<ActionItem>;


public class ActionItem
{
    #region Public Properties

    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }

    public int MachineId { get; set; }

    public OperationType OperationType { get; set; }

    public MachineOperationStatus OperationStatus { get; set; }

    public string PackageId { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    public TabType TabType { get; set; }

    public PageType PageType { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

I would like to join two lists ListA and ListB taking under considiration ONLY MachineId and PackageId.

```
IEnumerable<ActionItem> collection = this.ListA .Union(this.ListB);
```

The problem is that ListA may NOT have all the object's data filled in. So for example:

```
ListA will have machineId = 19, packageId = "abc"
```

and the rest will be default values.

```
ListB will have machineId = 19, packageId = "abc", StartTime = "2/3/2012".
```

So I would like to get a result of 1 row with the following:
machineId = 19, packageId = "abc", StartTime = "2/3/2012".

Since ListA has missing info, executing Union operation returns 2 rows instead of one. I would like for the result to return info from ListB (since ListB will always have more info, UNLESS ListB does not have that item (machineId, packageId)) maching only on machineId and packageId.

thanks

Comment: check the answer and do that update might work for you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
  //Create one list list containing all records
  var test = listA.Union(listB);

  //Group items based off the MachineId
  var lookup = test.ToLookup(t => new {t.MachineId, t.PackageId});

  //Final List
  var listC = new List<ActionItem>();

  foreach (var item in lookup)
  {
    var newItem = new ActionItem();

    newItem.MachineId = item.Key.MachineId;
    newItem.PackageId = item.Key.PackageId;

    newItem.ConnectionId = item.Max(i => i.ConnectionId);
    newItem.OperationStatus = item.Max(i => i.OperationStatus);
    newItem.OperationType = item.Max(i => i.OperationType);
    newItem.PageType = item.Max(i => i.PageType);
    newItem.StartTime = item.Max(i => i.StartTime);
    newItem.TabType = item.Max(i => i.TabType);

    listC.Add(newItem);
  }
```

listC would have the combined information per item.